# CRM Dynamics access to records

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have a question, and I hope somebody will be able to help.

In CRM Dynamics I have a single business unit called 'Business Unit A' but each user from it is able to see all the records. However, I would like to restrict the access to my records so I was thinking to do the following:

- add a new Business Unit B (Child of Business Unit A) - users can see only Contacts if firstname = Richard with all the associated records
- add a new Business Unit C (Child of Business Unit A) - so users can see only Contacts if firstname = Ben with all the associated records

But my question is what is the best way to make the records available to 'Business Unit B' or 'Business Unit C' if the record will be created by user from 'Business Unit A'? Do I need to create a workflow for example if new record is created and first name = Richard then assign record to 'Business Unit B'? What about the child records linked with Contacts (for example: Order, or an custom entities linked with it), do I need to create a workflow to assign those records also?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you review and understand the CRM security concepts and model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/wp-security-cds

I'm also very hesitant in creating and using additional / child business units.  Business units can add complexity.  Could teams be a viable solution for segregating records?

I'm not sure I understand your requirement, if its based on a contacts name, you would need to assign the record to a user or team in the relevant BU (Again I'd strongly consider teams vs BUs).  You'd also need to consider if the ownership should change if the name is changed?  You also need to consider all relationships and their properties to ensure assignment cascading occurs as you expect. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/configure-entity-relationship-cascading-behavior)

With regards to how to implement this, a background workflow could be sufficient.  Be cautious of the number of related / child records that are also getting assigned, as this could trigger a very long running process and some child records may not be fully/ properly assigned before a user begins working on the newly assigned initial record.  This is especially critical if reassignment can occur on change of a record.